# XSD validate element name as variable

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have a list XML elements and I'm trying to write an XSD to validate it. My goal is two-fold. First I would like that the elements' name is a variable (that way I don't force the user to put an specific value). However this variable (the element name) should be checked afterwards against a pool of possible values.

```
  <List>
    <Elem name="this_should_be_a_variable">
            <SomeProperty name="X"></Property>
    </Elem>
    <Elem name="this_should_be_a_variable">
            <SomeProperty name="X"></Property>
    </Elem>
</List>
```

So for example I would like to be able to, given an < Elem> check if it's name is [Blue, Red, White] and reject the XML otherwise.

EDIT

My xsd so far looks like this:

```
<xsd:complexType name="List">
    <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="here_i_dont_want_to_force_the_name" type="elem" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

And my question is how do I validate the name without explicitly setting it on the xsd:element ?

Comment: What exactly is the question? How far have you come with your XSD?

Comment: Is "[Blue, Red, White]" a fixed/constant list, or is that an example?

Comment: Is an example, I have (for now) 2 possible names for the elements. Red, blue, white was an example.

Comment: All right, but I mean, is the total "pool of possible values" known to you at the time of deployment for your XSD file?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [`xsd:choice` element](http://www.xmlschemareference.com/choiceElement.html). As you have already defined a reusable type for your inner elements, you can declare several elements in an `xsd:choice` element (where `xsd:choice` means that one of the contained elements needs to appear) with different names, always referring to the same type (if that is what's desired):

```
<xsd:complexType name="List">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:choice>
            <xsd:element name="Blue" type="elem" />
            <xsd:element name="Red" type="elem" />
            <xsd:element name="White" type="elem" />
        </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

As the `xsd:choice` element is wrapped in an `xsd:sequence` element, the choice can be repeated.

Comment: Could the downvoter explain why they didn't like this solution, please?